# How to display upload binary on itunes connect using xcode 8.1

Tags: ios10-today-widget, xcode8

I'm trying to upload a new version of my app to the apple store, but
   itunes connect looks to be bugged.

I already uploaded the binary 10 times with success, and so far, it
   didn't show up on the "Build" section. I'm using Xcode 8.1 and
   Application Loader 3.6. So I met all requirements.[enter image
   description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWmou.png)

After some time this disapper.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EtV8.png)

Comment: Have you received any mail after uploading to admin Id?

Comment: Yes, We have got below issue:

Comment: Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app includes an API for Apple's Push Notification service, but the aps-environment entitlement is missing from the app's signature.To resolve this, make sure your App ID is enabled for push notification in the Provisioning Portal..

Comment: Then, sign your app with a distribution provisioning profile that includes the aps-environment entitlement. This will create the correct signature, and you can resubmit your app. See "Provisioning and Development" in the Local and Push Notification Programming Guide for more information.

Comment: If your app does not use the Apple Push Notification service, no action is required. You may remove the API from future submissions to stop this warning. If you use a third-party framework, you may need to contact the developer for information on removing the API.